# How changing Product Price Alert email template (it is hard coded)

Tags: product, alert

It seems product_price_alert.html is the only hard coded template. I would like to change this template but there is only one variable inside var alertGrid. I tried to find in what file is formed this variable, the html code which is pasted by Magento inside that template but without success. If anyone knows how to solve this I appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Email` and the `send()` method, you can see that `alertGrid` can actually depend on the type of request being made.

It is one of either `productalert/email_price` or `productalert/email_stock`.

The templates for these are `productalert/price.phtml` or `productalert/stock.phtml` respectively which I believe map to `template/email/productalert/xxxx.phtml`

Comment: Thank you Douglas I found the templates for email in other place than usual. I don't know why they didn't follow the same rules like for other emails which are in locale folder.  I will adapt them to my template.

Answer (score 2):

For Magento 2 It's

`vendor\magento\module-product-alert\view\frontend\email\price_alert.html`

Comment: I tried to override stock.phtml for changing text. But no luck. Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the files here:

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/productalert

I don't know why they split the email template for these alerts into design folder instead of locale/emails. Pretty stupid!